# How can i separate a string from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, web

Im taking info from a mongodb server and one of the values is a string like this

```
Fire, Water, Ice, Steel
```

Sadly its not an array and will be hard to separate. How can i do this?

Comment: Sorry I answered but just realised the "...will be hard to separate..." comment....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sadly its not an array and will be hard to separate. How can i do
>   this?

You can make use of [the split() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to solve this problem.

**Example:**

```
var myString = 'Fire, Water, Ice, Steel';
var myArray = myString.split(', ');
console.log(myArray); // [ 'Fire', 'Water', 'Ice', 'Steel' ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the javascript split function, this will return you an array of parts.

```
var str = "Fire, Water, Ice, Steel".split(", ");
console.log(str); // ["Fire", "Water", "Ice", "Steel"];
```